# Where is my views-view-field.tpl.php and the other views templates

Tags: views, theming, location

I can not find my vviews templates, where are they?
In my `/modules/` I don't have a `views` sub dir and in `/sites/all/themes/modules` I have a sub dir called `views_php` which doesn't seem to contain the view templates either.. where do I find these files?

**edit 1**

My directory structure looks something like this:

```
sites/
  all/ 
    libraries/
    modules/
      alchemy/
      apps/
      ...
      ...
      views_php/
        plugins/
          views/
      ...
      ...
    themes/
      marinelli/
```

In my db there is some content in tables `drupal_viws_display` and `drupal_views_view` and a `drupal_cache_viws` and `drupal_cache_views_data` also exists - with content.

**edit 2**

I downloaded the whole ftp directory and tried to find my `Views` templates:

```
$ find . -name "*view**.tpl*"
./sites/all/modules/commerce_kickstart/modules/commerce_kickstart/commerce_kickstart_taxonomy/theme/views-view--collection-products--page.tpl.php
./sites/all/modules/commerce_kickstart/modules/contrib/views_megarow/theme/views-view-table.tpl.php
./sites/all/modules/commerce_kickstart/modules/contrib/views/tests/templates/views-view--frontpage.tpl.php
./sites/all/modules/commerce_kickstart/modules/contrib/views/theme/views-view-grid.tpl.php
./sites/all/modules/commerce_kickstart/modules/contrib/views/theme/views-view-unformatted.tpl.php
./sites/all/modules/commerce_kickstart/modules/contrib/views/theme/views-ui-edit-item.tpl.php
./sites/all/modules/commerce_kickstart/modules/contrib/views/theme/views-view-row-rss.tpl.php
./sites/all/modules/commerce_kickstart/modules/contrib/views/theme/views-view-field.tpl.php
./sites/all/modules/commerce_kickstart/modules/contrib/views/theme/views-view-fields.tpl.php
./sites/all/modules/commerce_kickstart/modules/contrib/views/theme/views-view-table.tpl.php
./sites/all/modules/commerce_kickstart/modules/contrib/views/theme/views-exposed-form.tpl.php
./sites/all/modules/commerce_kickstart/modules/contrib/views/theme/views-view-grouping.tpl.php
./sites/all/modules/commerce_kickstart/modules/contrib/views/theme/views-ui-display-tab-bucket.tpl.php
./sites/all/modules/commerce_kickstart/modules/contrib/views/theme/views-view-list.tpl.php
./sites/all/modules/commerce_kickstart/modules/contrib/views/theme/views-ui-display-tab-setting.tpl.php
./sites/all/modules/commerce_kickstart/modules/contrib/views/theme/views-ui-edit-view.tpl.php
./sites/all/modules/commerce_kickstart/modules/contrib/views/theme/views-view-row-comment.tpl.php
./sites/all/modules/commerce_kickstart/modules/contrib/views/theme/views-view-summary-unformatted.tpl.php
./sites/all/modules/commerce_kickstart/modules/contrib/views/theme/views-view.tpl.php
./sites/all/modules/commerce_kickstart/modules/contrib/views/theme/views-more.tpl.php
./sites/all/modules/commerce_kickstart/modules/contrib/views/theme/views-view-rss.tpl.php
./sites/all/modules/commerce_kickstart/modules/contrib/views/theme/views-view-summary.tpl.php
./sites/all/modules/commerce_kickstart/modules/contrib/eva/eva-display-entity-view.tpl.php
./sites/all/modules/commerce_kickstart/modules/contrib/date/date_views/theme/date-views-pager.tpl.php
./sites/all/modules/commerce_kickstart/modules/contrib/date/date_views/theme/date-views-filter-form.tpl.php
./sites/all/modules/date/date_views/theme/date-views-pager.tpl.php
./sites/all/modules/date/date_views/theme/date-views-filter-form.tpl.php
./conference/sites/all/modules/views/tests/templates/views-view--frontpage.tpl.php
./conference/sites/all/modules/views/theme/views-view-grid.tpl.php
./conference/sites/all/modules/views/theme/views-view-unformatted.tpl.php
./conference/sites/all/modules/views/theme/views-ui-edit-item.tpl.php
./conference/sites/all/modules/views/theme/views-view-row-rss.tpl.php
./conference/sites/all/modules/views/theme/views-view-field.tpl.php
./conference/sites/all/modules/views/theme/views-view-fields.tpl.php
./conference/sites/all/modules/views/theme/views-view-table.tpl.php
./conference/sites/all/modules/views/theme/views-exposed-form.tpl.php
./conference/sites/all/modules/views/theme/views-view-grouping.tpl.php
./conference/sites/all/modules/views/theme/views-ui-display-tab-bucket.tpl.php
./conference/sites/all/modules/views/theme/views-view-list.tpl.php
./conference/sites/all/modules/views/theme/views-ui-display-tab-setting.tpl.php
./conference/sites/all/modules/views/theme/views-ui-edit-view.tpl.php
./conference/sites/all/modules/views/theme/views-view-row-comment.tpl.php
./conference/sites/all/modules/views/theme/views-view-summary-unformatted.tpl.php
./conference/sites/all/modules/views/theme/views-view.tpl.php
./conference/sites/all/modules/views/theme/views-more.tpl.php
./conference/sites/all/modules/views/theme/views-view-rss.tpl.php
./conference/sites/all/modules/views/theme/views-view-summary.tpl.php
./conference/sites/all/modules/date/date_views/theme/date-views-pager.tpl.php
./conference/sites/all/modules/date/date_views/theme/date-views-filter-form.tpl.php
```

$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that `views` I was using wasn't the real `views` but rather part of `ecommerce-kickstart` which I have uninstalled in the meantime and that forced me to re-install `Views` which also gave me access to all the templates

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't sound like you have the views module installed. [Views_php](https://drupal.org/project/views_php) is a different module.

The modules page (example.com/admin/modules) should tell you whether you have Views installed and enabled. If you don't see Views (just "Views") in the list, then you don't have it installed. If that's the case, head over to https://drupal.org/project/views, download and untar/unzip the appropriate version into your sites/all/modules (or sites/default/modules) directory. Go back to the modules page and enable it.

If all else fails, why not do a file system search for 'views.module' ?

Comment: I have Views installed! I have created my own Views under `admin/structure/views` and in `admin/modules` `Views` shos up, installed and enabled just fine! As for the file system search, I'm connected to a remote host (GoDaddy) by `ftp` only.

Comment: When you ran the query suggested by RajeevK, are you absolutely sure you were using the right DB? If you have views installed, that query should return something. The only places a module can be is (1) sites/default/modules (or a subdir of that), (2) sites/all/modules (or a subdir of that), or (3) modules directory at the root of the site (which is really the wrong place for it, but should still work).

Comment: As a last resort, why not download the entire site via FTP and do a filesystem search on your own machine?

If that doesn't yield anything, then the site you're looking at via FTP is not the one you're working with via the UI. :-)

Comment: I'm doing just what you suggested lastm, I can't believe it but Views is instaaled and enabled and I'm using it on my site - works just fine but contents can't be found... yet! - let's see!

Answer (score 0):

First ensure you have `views` enabled from the list of module.

**Then**

You can find all `views` related templates in the `theme` directory inside `views` module. Proper location --

**sites/all/modules/views/theme**

In your case it's location is

**/sites/all/modules/commerce_kickstart/modules/contrib/views/theme/**